# How I can handle Kestrel errors?

Tags: .net-core, c#-3.0, kestrel-http-server

Kestrel writes logs. Sometimes it's `info` messages, sometimes - messages with `warning`/`error` type.

Here is console output:

[image]
it's common.

I would like to catch exceptions to send notification via messenger or email to developer.

A fast research gives me something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#exception-handler-lambda) but I don't understand how I can catch stack trace and exception message. Has somebody a working example of this?

P.S. I use Asp.Net Core 3.0